# sql shows ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

The following sql code show the error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
What changes are required?

```
CREATE TABLE employees1 (
    e_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name VARCHAR(20),
    salary NUMBER(37),
    dept_name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO employees1(1,'A',10000,'CSE')
INSERT INTO employees1(2,'B',20000,'CCE')
INSERT INTO employees1(3,'C',30000,'CSE')
INSERT INTO employees1(4,'D',40000,'IT')
INSERT INTO employees1(5,'E',50000,'MECH')

SELECT* FROM employees1;
```

Comment: You are missing semicolons and the value clause: `INSERT INTO employees1 VALUES (1,'A',10000,'CSE');` or better even: `INSERT INTO employees1 (e_id, f_name, salary, dept_name) VALUES (1,'A',10000,'CSE');`. We don't use `VARCHAR` in Oracle by the way, but use `VARCHAR2` instead. And `NUMBER(37)`? Wow, they can earn a lot in your company it seems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statements do not end with semicolons.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: _"It still doesn't work"_  Well, we can't see what you did.  Please update your question with a copy and paste (formatted as code) of what "still doesn't work".

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `values` after table name in insert statements and semicolon(`;`) at the end of each insert statement.

Create table statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE employees1 (
     e_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
     f_name VARCHAR(20),
     salary NUMBER(37),
     dept_name VARCHAR(10)
 );
```

Insert statements:

```
 INSERT INTO employees1 values(1,'A',10000,'CSE');

 INSERT INTO employees1 values(2,'B',20000,'CCE');

 INSERT INTO employees1 values(3,'C',30000,'CSE');

 INSERT INTO employees1 values(4,'D',40000,'IT');

 INSERT INTO employees1 values(5,'E',50000,'MECH');
```

Select statement:

```
 SELECT* FROM employees1;
```

Output:

| E_ID | F_NAME | SALARY | DEPT_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10000 | CSE |
| 2 | B | 20000 | CCE |
| 3 | C | 30000 | CSE |
| 4 | D | 40000 | IT |
| 5 | E | 50000 | MECH |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2d8d1db4e368ad8b4d750255d3d08b7b)*